# Postgresql - combining UPDATE, Windows Functions and Conditioning int a single SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE json2
(
  started boolean,
  the_geom text,
  created_at timestamp with time zone,
  updated_at timestamp with time zone,
  lat double precision,
  lon double precision,
  cartodb_id integer,
  row_id serial NOT NULL,
  ts text,
  timespent integer,
  ts_int bigint,
  CONSTRAINT json2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (row_id)
)
```

and the following two working SQL statements:

A) Calculates the difference between the current row's **ts_int** value and the previous row's **ts_int** value

```
    SELECT
        ts_int - LAG(ts_int,1)
        OVER(ORDER BY row_id)
    FROM json2;
```

B) Simple condition statement that fills values within the **timespent** column depending on the value of the **started** column's value.

```
    UPDATE json2 
        SET timespent = CASE
        WHEN started = TRUE THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END;
```

I want to be able to update table **json2** by writing the result of statement *(A)* into column **timespent** within the conditional statement *(B)*.

Means (pseudo code):

> if **started** = TRUE then **timespent** = 0
>   else **timespent** = **ts_int**(this row) - **ts_int**(previous row)

How should I do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html

```
WITH query_a ....
UPDATE json2
SET column-from-json2 = column-from-query-a ....
FROM query_a
WHERE join-condition-between-query_a-and-json2
```

Try this query:

```
WITH query_a AS (
  SELECT row_id, 
         ts_int - LAG(ts_int,1) 
            OVER(ORDER BY row_id)  As ts_int
  FROM json2
)

UPDATE json2
SET timespent = CASE started
                  WHEN true THEN 0
                  ELSE query_a.ts_int
                END
FROM query_a
WHERE json2.row_id = query_a.row_id
;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8f608/1